# Getting the "Media Created" date of a video file in UWP

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, windows-10-universal

I want to get the date of creation of a video file, commonly known as **Media Created** property (not to be confused with the **File Creation Date**)

I'm trying with this code:

```
var clip = await MediaClip.CreateFromFileAsync(x);
var encodingProps = clip.GetVideoEncodingProperties();
var props = encodingProps.Properties.ToList();
```

Inside the `props` reference I'm getting a list of Guids and values, but I'm lost there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Extended properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-getting-file-properties#getting-a-files-extended-properties) to get the specific property you need:

```
var dateEncodedPropertyName = "System.Media.DateEncoded";
var propertyNames = new List<string>()
{
    dateEncodedPropertyName
};

// Get extended properties
IDictionary<string, object> extraProperties =
    await file.Properties.RetrievePropertiesAsync(propertyNames);

// Get the property value
var propValue = extraProperties[dateEncodedPropertyName];
if (propValue != null)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(propValue);
}
```

Note I am using the [`System.Media.DateEncoded` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/properties/props-system-media-dateencoded) in the example. If you need a different property, check out the full list of supported properties with their exact names in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/properties/core-bumper).